# Is the dequeue count of an activemq topic a multiple of the number of its consumers?

Tags: activemq-classic

If I post 3 messages to a topic with 2 active consumers, what will the dequeue count be after all messages are successfully consumed, 3 or 6? From my JConsole I think 6 (it shows enQ=3 and deQ=6) but can you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your assumption is correct. But keep in mind that it might not always be an exact multiple, if one of the consumers disconnects for a period of time and then reconnects, the dequeue count will not include the messages missed by that client while it was disconnected.